# Non-blocking connect timeout

Tags: c++, linux, tcp

I'm perform non blocking connect to server.

What an appropriate timeout value to be used in *select* to consider the server down/busy?

**P.S.**

Connect can fail since server is down or busy.

In case server is down I always will always end with select timeout.

More interesting case is when server is busy. IMHO 1 sec is enough for TCP handshake. If it takes too long time to connect to server, than all communication with the server will be delayed. So would it be reasonable decision wait on *select* max 1 sec?

Comment: This question does not have a definite answer. I don't think this is your fault, it is just a very difficult problem, and you will have to do some trial-and-error to find a value that works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packets can be lost in which case the node will resend it after a timeout so do not use a value that's just enough for a handshake. You can play a bit with `tcpdump`, break the connection (unplug the ethernet cable) and see what's happening.

Something like 10-20 seconds should be fine, but this is depends on how important your task is...

Answer (score 1):

The connection to the server should be almost immediately.  I think this could be somewhat subjective, but a few seconds should be more than sufficient.  For some recent work we used 10 seconds, which has caught all of our cases.

Answer (score 0):

That's up to you really, but I imagine something like 10-20 seconds would be a reasonable time out.

[Apache's default KeepAliveTimeout is 15 seconds](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#keepalivetimeout), so that's one standard you could use.

Comment: I think they talk about other timeout: "Amount of time the server will wait for subsequent requests on a persistent connection".

Comment: @dimba: True, they aren't the same thing, but they're both timeouts for requests to remote machines, so they would be in the same ballpark.